# How to declare mobx prop types using typescript, react and mobx

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx

I have a functional root component like below

```
const RootPage: React.FC = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Sidebar/>
            <Grid container className={classes.fullHeight}>
                <Map/>
            </Grid>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
};
```

and my map component is looking like below

```
interface IMapProps {
    map:MapStore;
}

const Map : React.FC<IMapProps> = (props)=>{
    return (
        <div>
            {props.map}
        </div>
    )
};

export default (inject('map'))(observer(Map));
```

I am expecting IMapProps to obviously come from the mobx injection; however, typescript is throwing error saying that I should provide the props in the root component.  Error looks like below

```
react_front_1    | Property 'map' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'IMapProps'.  TS2741
react_front_1    | 
react_front_1    |     22 |             <Sidebar/>
react_front_1    |     23 |             <Grid container className={classes.fullHeight}>
react_front_1    |   > 24 |                 <Map/>
react_front_1    |        |                  ^
react_front_1    |     25 |             </Grid>
react_front_1    |     26 |         </React.Fragment>
react_front_1    |     27 |     )
```

How do I provide types for props that come from the mobx store?

Comment: I have the exact same question, but it seems there is no good way to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mark them as optional props.

```
interface IMapProps {
    map?: MapStore;
}
```

Although you might need to use non-null assertion after that, like `props.map!` if your tsconfig is set to strict.

Better way right now is to use `React.createContext` and make custom hook to get the store(s)

```
const store = useStore()
```

This way you don't even need to describe props interface because your store(s) will come from this hook.

More info here:
https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html#using-external-state-in-observer-components